# Why aren't my Route components rendering?

Tags: react-router, reactjs, react-router-v4

I have some `Route` components that I am using to dynamically generate the routes based on what pages are set in the CMS (which I am accessing via an API) using react-router 4. I have got these pages cached and then set in the initial state for ease of access.

I am trying to loop through the pages set and match the page to a component based on what template is set for that page.

```
class Routes extends Component {

  getRoutes(){

    const routes = map(this.props.pages, (page, key) => {
      switch(page.template){
        case 'home':
          return <Route exact path={`${page.path}`} component={Home} key={key}/>
        case 'about':
          return <Route path={`${page.path}`} component={About} key={key}/>
        case 'campaign':
          return <Route path={`${page.path}`} component={Campaign} key={key}/>
        case 'product':
          return <Route path={`${page.path}`} component={Product} key={key}/>
        case 'article':
          return <Route path={`${page.path}`} component={Article} key={key}/>
        case 'contact':
          return <Route path={`${page.path}`} component={Contact} key={key}/>
        default:
          throw new Error(`No page container matching page's template - ${page.template}`)
      }
    })

    return (
      <Switch>
        {routes}
        <Route component={NoMatch}/>
      </Switch>
    )
  }

  render() {

    const routes = this.getRoutes;

    return (
      {routes}
    )
  }
}
```

I am getting an error:

> Invariant Violation: `Routes.render()`: A valid React element (or null) must be returned. You may have returned undefined, an array or some other invalid object.

I suspect because the loop is taking time to run, the `routes` variable is set to an empty array so is throwing that error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I suspect because the loop is taking time to run, the `routes` variable is set to an empty array so is throwing that error?

That isn't correct, the loop is synchronous. `routes` will not be empty.

The problem is you're returning wrong. You have to return a JSX element but your code currently is:

1. Invalid JSX, inline JSX expressions *must have a parent element*, plus the interpreter is actually interpreting it as `({ routes })` which *is an invalid object for `render`* thus the error message
2. Your inline JSX is a method reference: `this.getRoutes`, you need to execute it for the return value: `this.getRoutes()`

Instead, do this:

```
render() {
  <div>
    {this.getRoutes()} 
  </div>
}
```

So that there is a parent to the inline expression, or you could get rid of the parent altogether for conciseness:

```
render() {
    return this.getRoutes();
}
```

This will return the corresponding `<Route>` component.

Comment: Nailed it! Thanks Andrew